# Django authentication: index for staff and index for user (2 templates)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-authentication

I have 2 functions currently working, one is a specific view for **is_staff** users, the other for any users.
Right now after staff logs in they can add path **/dashboard** to the URL and can access the route, while normal users cannot view it. That is expected and good.

Problem: I want to at login, to redirect **user.is_staff** straight to this path **/dashboard**, instead of going to index first.

The functions somehow I think I have to merge:
(views.py)

```
  1 @staff_member_required
  2 def staff_dashboard(request):
  3     users = User.objects.all()
  4     customer = Customer.objects.all()
  5     accounts = Account.objects.all()
  6     context = {
  7             'users': users,
  8             'customer': customer,
  9             'accounts': accounts
 10             }
 11     return render(request, 'bank_app/dashboard.html', context)
 12
 13
 14 @login_required
 15 def index(request):
 16     customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user)
 17     accounts = Account.objects.filter(user=request.user)
 18     context = {
 19             'customer': customer,
 20             'accounts': accounts
 21             }
 22     return render(request, 'bank_app/index.html', context)
```

(urls.py:)

```
urlpatterns = [
         path('dashboard', views.staff_dashboard, name='staff_dashboard'),
         path('', views.index, name='index'),
         path('create', views.create, name='create'),
         path('createaccount', views.createaccount, name='createaccount'),
         path('details/<int:pk>', views.details, name='details'),
        ]
```

When user is_staff, show "`dashboard/`"(dashboard.html), not `""`(index.html)

*I also have extension template seen below but that did not fix the issue:

```
 28    <p>Welcome {{ user }}</p>
 29
 30     {% if user.is_staff  %}
 31         {% block staffcontent  %}
 32         {% endblock %}
 33     {% else %}
 34         {% block content %}
 35         {% endblock %}
 36     {% endif %}
 37
 38       {% block footer %}
 39       {% endblock %}
```

################### **UPDATE** ####################

So far this works, but I still need to refactor:

```
10 @login_required  
11 def index(request):  
12     if request.user.is_staff:  
##13        @staff_member_required  
##14       def staff_dashboard(request):  
15             users = User.objects.all()  
16             customer = Customer.objects.all()  
17             accounts = Account.objects.all()  
18             context = {  
19                     'users': users,  
20                'customer': customer,  
21                     'accounts': accounts  
22 }  
23             return render(request, 'bank_app/dashboard.html', context)  
##24             return HttpResponseRedirect('staff_dashboard')  
25     else:  
##26          def user_dashboard():  
27             customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user)  
28             accounts = Account.objects.filter(user=request.user)  
29             context = {  
30                     'customer': customer,  
31                     'accounts': accounts  
32                     }  
33             return render(request, 'bank_app/index.html', context)  
34
```

I was instructed to use the decorator inside the statement- Teacher requirement :/ - (cause only staff can view part of the content) and use **HttpResponse** to display the correct html.
Any idea how to refactor this?

I am trying to add the logic seen on the commented out lines (##)

(urls.py):

```
5 urlpatterns = [
6           path('', views.index, name='index'),
##7         path('staff_dashboard', views.index, name='staff_dashboard'),
##8         path('user_dashboard/', views.index, name='user_dashboard'),
```

**############## SOLUTION ###################**

As suggested in the comments, I have fixed the urls.py and split the request in views.py:

```
  1 @login_required
  2 def index(request):
  3     if request.user.is_staff:
  4         return HttpResponseRedirect('staff_dashboard/')
  5     else:
  6         return HttpResponseRedirect('user_dashboard/')
  7
  8
  9 @staff_member_required
 10 def staff_dashboard(request):
 11     users = User.objects.all()
 12     customer = Customer.objects.all()
 13     accounts = Account.objects.all()
 14     context = {
 15             'users': users,
 16             'customer': customer,
 17             'accounts': accounts
 18             }
 19     return render(request, 'bank_app/dashboard.html', context)
 20
 21
 22 @login_required
 23 def user_dashboard(request):
 24     customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user)
 25     accounts = Account.objects.filter(user=request.user)
 26     context = {
 27             'customer': customer,
 28             'accounts': accounts
 29             }
 30     return render(request, 'bank_app/index.html', context)
```

(urls.py):

```
  1 urlpatterns = [
  2         path('', views.index, name='index'),
  3         path('staff_dashboard/', views.staff_dashboard, name='staff_dashboard'),
  4         path('user_dashboard/', views.user_dashboard, name='user_dashboard'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this.

```
@login_required
 def index(request):
      if request.user.is_superuser:
           return redirect('staff_dashboard')
      else:
          customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user)
          accounts = Account.objects.filter(user=request.user)
          context = {
             'customer': customer,
            'accounts': accounts
             }

          return render(request, 'bank_app/index.html', context)
```

To check whether a user is is_staff you can do something like this **user.is_staff or user.is_superuser**.
let me know if it works.

Comment: The logic worked, but I still need to refactor and add the **@staff_member_required** decorator inside the if-else. On the function for the **index** view, I need to either show "dashboard.html" or "index.html" (depending on the user role)

I have updated more details to the question, could you please have a look?

Comment: @patbet what you did not is not good at all.your def user_dashboard(request) and def staff_dashboard(request) should have their owns urls.and after that inside your index you can use "redirect()" to redirect the use to these urls after your conditions.

Comment: When I add the correct URL so  `path('staff_dashboard', views.staff_dashboard, name......` 
I get an error:  **module 'bank_app.views' has no attribute 'staff_dashboard'**
Which makes sense, since in views I am not calling `staff_dashboard` straight forward, but I have it inside the main function `def index(request)` - and that is why in urls.py I set `views.index` for them all.
Does that make sense?

Comment: @patbet first create a function "staff_dashboard" inside the views.py and add your url for it.like you did before.and then do the samething same thing for "user_dashboard".and after all this your create def index(request) and then inside this function you make the conditions i wrote here and just redirect the user to the specific view.

Comment: Stack overflow will always be the best source! It works after I followed your suggestion, thanks a lot!

Comment: @patbet i am happy i was able to help you )